# Firebase Firestore avoid retriving same data multiple times when quickly switching back and forth through fragments

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-viewpager, firebase-storage

I'm making an app that allows you to buy tickets for a club event. I have a **HomeActivity** activity which contains a **bottom navigation bar** and a frame layout allowing me to navigate through 4 fragments.

One of those fragments has a **ViewPager** that contains cards with club details, allowing you to swipe through them. Club details are retrived from Firebase Firestore, and club logos from Firebase Storage, all stored in an array of custom Club objects.

The problem is if I quickly switch between this fragment and another one a couple of times, the same data is displayed multiple times (for the number of times I switched back to the Clubs ViewPager fragment). The same problem appears if I spam the bottom navigation bar button for this fragment.

**Things I have tried :**

1. Clearing the clubs array in the OnViewCreated() method in fragment
2. setRetainInstance(true) in the OnAttach() method

My assumption is that when I place multiple queries to firebase, they continue being executed even when I switch fragments adding more and more clubs to the array. If that is true I'm not sure why clearing the array doesn't fix my problem.

**Here's the ClubsFragment.class code**

public class ClubsFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String TAG = "ClubFragment";
private static FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private static FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


private static ArrayList<Club> clubs = new ArrayList<>();
//private static ArrayList<Integer> colors;
//ArgbEvaluator argbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
private static PagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clubs, container, false);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(clubs, getContext());


    ViewPager viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


    //loadViewPagerTask task = new loadViewPagerTask((HomeActivity) getActivity());
    //task.execute();
    loadViewPager();

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

private void loadViewPager() {
    clubs.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    db.collection("clubs").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Successfully retrieved documents, clearing old array");

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    final Club temp = new Club(document.getString("img_loc"),
                            document.getString("name"),
                            document.getString("desc"));

                    StorageReference reference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(temp.getImageRef());
                    reference.getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            temp.setImg(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
                            temp.setColor(Palette.from(temp.getImg()).generate().getDarkVibrantColor(0x651FFF));
                            //colors.add(temp.getColor());
                            clubs.add(temp);


                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error loading images: ", e);
                        }
                    });


                }


            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }

    });
}
```

EDIT: Removed async task as recommended in comment below.

Comment: Don't use AsyncTask. It's deprecated, and unnecessary since Firebase APIs are already all asynchronous.

Comment: That makes my code much more simple, thank you. Unfortunately still doesn't fix my issue. I updated my question.